# PhoneGap Build: confusing and conflicting information?

Tags: cordova, command-line-interface

I'm using Phonegap build to create a simple app.

in my conf.xml file I have chosen the cli version like this:

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value='cli-6.5.0' />
```

But when I upload my app to Phonegap build, I get the below error:

[image]

This is confusing and doesn't make sense.

Is this the phonegap build error or I'm actually missing something?

Answer (score 0):

**The latest Phongap CLI Version is 6.5.0**

As you can see [here](https://build.phonegap.com/current-support) the default version is 6.5.0.

What you can do is remove that line in the config.xml file and by doing that it will use the most recent CLI (6.5.0)